# Panic : Could not connect : Dial TCP X.X.X.X:5432 : Connect : Connection refused

Tags: postgresql, docker, go, docker-compose, timescaledb

I'm trying to install TimeScaleDB using Docker Compose, but I get the following error when importing data using timescaledb-parallel-copy :

> /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running
> /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/import_data.sh timescaledb | panic: could
> not connect: dial tcp 172.18.0.2:5432: connect: connection refused
> timescaledb | timescaledb | goroutine 6 [running]: timescaledb |
> main.processBatches(0xc000016730, 0xc000060780) timescaledb |
> /go/src/github.com/timescale/timescaledb-parallel-copy/cmd/timescaledb-parallel-copy/main.go:238
> +0x8bb timescaledb | created by main.main timescaledb | /go/src/github.com/timescale/timescaledb-parallel-copy/cmd/timescaledb-parallel-copy/main.go:148
> +0x1d2 timescaledb | panic: could not connect: dial tcp 172.18.0.2:5432: connect: connection refused

Here's my docker compose and my docker file :

Docker compose :

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  timescaledb:
    container_name: timescaledb
    build:
      context: "./timescaledb"
      dockerfile: "docker_file"
    env_file:
      - "./timescaledb/environment.env"
    volumes:
      - "./timescaledb/data:/data"
    ports:
      - "5432:5432/tcp"
    networks:
      - local_network
    restart: on-failure
networks:
  local_network:
```

Docker file :

```
FROM timescale/timescaledb:latest-pg13
ADD create_tables.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
ADD import_data.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
RUN chmod a+r /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*
```

And here's the import_data.sh script that calls timescaledb-parallel-copy :

```
#!/bin/bash
timescaledb-parallel-copy --connection "host=timescaledb user=postgres password=XXX sslmode=disable" --db-name YYY --table ZZZ --copy-options "CSV" -skip-header --columns "name, unit" --file "/data/data.csv" --reporting-period 30s workers 4
```

I also tried using localhost, but I get the same error.

Comment: Hello Manele, checking back in some notes we have in Timescale slack community of someone having the same error. They found that the word disable after sslmode had to be in " marks, but because the phrase is already enclosed in "" that was a pain. However, sslmode=disable is the default and so you don't need it strictly speaking. 

Worth a try?

If you want to keep it in, you might have to add escape characters?

_Transparency: I work for Timescale_

Comment: @greenweeds I tried removing sslmode=disable but I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit : Problem solved. The host should not be specified in the connection string. According to the official documentation (https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres) :

> Also, as of docker-library/postgres#440, the temporary daemon started for these initialization scripts listens only on the Unix socket, so any psql usage should drop the hostname portion (see docker-library/postgres#474 (comment) for example).

Comment: For me, running Docker  Desktop on top of WSL, the command `wsl psql -U postgres -h 127.0.0.1` works, but `psql -U postgres -h 127.0.0.1` doesn't i.e. it works when I try to connect from Linux but not from Windows.